# How to use Firebase Cloud messaging with localytics

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, firebase-cloud-messaging

We are using GCM and Localytics for push notification, now when we are migrating from gcm to fcm this [document](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/android-migrate-fcm) suggesting to remove wakelock and some other permission and receiver from manifest file but localytics use these permission.

help me in migrating gcm to fcm

Comment: I also have this same doubt. How do you solved this?

Answer (score 0):

The required permissions are added into your manifest by the FCM library. This is why when using FCM you do not need to add them yourself. So if localytics uses the permissions added by FCM then you should be ok.